# Object sent -autorelease too many times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, autorelease

I have this code that simple returns Today's date as a string formatted:

```
+(NSString*) getTodayString_YYYY_MM_DD {

  NSDate    * today = [NSDate date];

  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; 

  return [[formatter stringFromDate:today] autorelease];

}
```

With instruments I'm not getting a memory leak, but when I Analyze, XCode says:

```
Object sent -autorelease too many times
```

If I understand correctly, I have to release manually the formatter as I'm creating it using 'alloc', but I can't release here because I have to return the value, so I add the autorelease.

How I can do it better to improve it ?

thanks,

r.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are -autoReleasing the NSString, not the formatter.

You don't need an autoRelease since -stringFromDate: is giving you an already autoReleased string.

Here is one way your code can look like:

```
+(NSString*) getTodayString_YYYY_MM_DD {

  NSDate    * today = [NSDate date];

  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; 

  NSString *retString = [formatter stringFromDate:today];
  [formatter release];

  return retString;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that an `NSDate`'s [`description`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188--description) is always in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM`:

```
+ (NSString *) getTodayString_YYYY_MM_DD
{
    return [[[NSDate date] description] substringToIndex:10];
}
```

Just throwing it out there. It's probably less efficient than the `NSDateFormatter` method.